# Is there any way to use a RecyclerView inside a ScrollView but not have it break the recycling functionality?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Right now, when you use a `RecyclerView` inside a scrollable view like `NestedScrollView`, the recycling doesn't work and every item in the list has its `onBindViewHolder()` called. Is there any way to put a `RecyclerView` inside a scrollable view but still have the Recycling work? I know I can flatten everything into a single `RecyclerView` with item view types, but I'd like to avoid that if possible as I have a bunch of unique view types which means a bunch of code.

Edit: I already know about `setNestedScrollingEnabled(false)`. That is not what I need. The problem is `RecyclerView`s inside nested scroll views won't recycle views and binds every item immediately. Go try it yourself.

Comment: Have you tried `setNestedScrollingEnabled(false)` ?

Comment: That is not what I want. I already know about that. The scrolling works fine, but the recycling of views don't work.

Comment: Why would you need that RV inside SV?

Comment: Because I have a bunch of unique views and then a list and they all need to be in a scrollable view. As I said in the original post, I am aware I can put that all in a RecyclerView with different item view types. But that means each unique view will need a separate POJO representation, ViewHolder, and xml layout. And that is code I can avoid if I can put a RecyclerView inside a ScrollView and have it work properly.

Answer (score 0):

No, putting a RecyclerView inside a scrolling container will not work, because the wrapping scrollable container needs to know the RecyclerViews height or width, which it only can *after* inflating all of its content.

If you want to display a lot of items you should display them all within the same RecyclerView, making use of different view types.

*I personally recommend [epoxy](https://github.com/airbnb/epoxy) which makes dealing with multiple different items easier.*